# How to change CSS Class style by JS

Tags: javascript

I have a css clas like this:

```
.title-bottom:before {
    bottom: -5px;
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
}
```

left:0 sets the underscore to left but when RTL active, it must be float right.So, I want to change left:0 to left:initial if rtl exist.

How can I do it? I started to write the code like this:

```
if (document.dir === 'rtl'){
```

but I couldnt continue it.Because I couldnt find good resources to learn JS.

I need a code for this problem, Also good resources to learn JS.

Comment: You need to add another class to the `.title-bottom` element like `.rtl` when rtl is active and remove it when it's not. Then in your css add `.rtl.title-bottom:before { left: initial; }`

Comment: Hi!, you can find anything you want in w3 schools [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) or mozilla developer [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeking to change a CSS rule for the entire document.

One way to do this is to append a style sheet to your document's `<head>`, and put the rule changes in there. Since the added style sheet is the last one in the document, it will override the default rule.

```js
if (document.dir === 'rtl') {

  // create a new style sheet and append to head
  let newStyle = document.createElement('style');
  newStyle.innerHTML = '.title-bottom:before { left:initial; }';
  document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
}
```

```js
function addRtl() {
  let newStyle = document.createElement('style');
  newStyle.innerHTML = '.title-bottom:before { content: ".rtl"; }';
  document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
  document.dir = 'rtl';
}
```

```css
.title-bottom {
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
<h1>RTL Style Manipulation</h1>
<button onclick="addRtl()">Add New Style Sheet</button>
<div class="title-bottom">.title-bottom</div>
</body>
```

Alternative Method: CSS Attributes

But since you are basing the changes on an attribute called 'dir', you don't need any JavaScript to accomplish this. Instead, you can make use of the [CSS [attribute=value] selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp).

The CSS attribute selector has the form `[attribute=value]`, which will match an element that has that attribute set to that value.

To make style modification when `document.dir === 'rtl'`, you would use:

```css
[dir*=rtl] .title-bottom:before {
  left:initial;
}
```

A little example showing how to use CSS attribute selector:

```js
function rtl() {
  document.dir = 'rtl';
}

function ltr() {
  document.dir = 'ltr';
}
```

```css
[dir=rtl] p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Change document.dir</h1>

<button onclick="rtl()">set rtl</button>
<button onclick="ltr()">set ltr</button>
<p>Paragraph text will be red when document.dir === 'rtl'</p>
```

Comment: @AhmetTaş Which code doesn't work? The code snippet is working as expected.

Comment: My css editor says "Attiribute css selectors with *= are slow!". Your css code works but I wonder will it slow my website?

Comment: @AhmetTaş Since you're only concerned with the document's `dir` value, you can remove the `*` from the selector. This will be faster. See the updated answer.